# Streaming to Facebook Live with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming

I've set up an RTMP/RTSP streaming-service with [MediaMTX](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx) on my desktop.

From OBS Studio, I'm then streaming to:

```
Server: rtmp://localhost/
Stream Key: stream
```

This leaves me with 2 streams:

```
RTMP: rtmp://localhost/stream
RTSP: rtsp://localhost:8554/stream
```

MediaMTX is then set up to re-distribute the stream to YouTube, Twitch, and Facebook simultaneously, using `ffmpeg`.

Streaming to YouTube and Twitch is no problem. But whenever I'm trying to stream to Facebook, I always get timeout errors.

**The command**

```
C:/mediamtx_v1.3.0/ffmpeg.exe -i "rtmp://localhost/stream"
-c:v libx264 -b:v 4500k -r 60 -g 120 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOUTUBE_STREAM_KEY"
-c copy -f flv "rtmp://ber.contribute.live-video.net/app/TWITCH_STREAM_KEY"
-c copy -f flv rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FACEBOOK_STREAM_KEY
```

This part of the code, is what fails:

```
-c copy -f flv rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FACEBOOK_STREAM_KEY
```

Let's try broadcasting to Facebook only:

```
C:/mediamtx_v1.3.0/ffmpeg.exe -i "rtmp://localhost/stream" -c copy -f flv rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FACEBOOK_STREAM_KEY


    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF MediaMTX v1.3.0
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF configuration loaded from C:\mediamtx_v1.3.0\mediamtx.yml
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF [RTSP] listener opened on :8554 (TCP), :8000 (UDP/RTP), :8001 (UDP/RTCP)
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF [RTMP] listener opened on :1935
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF [HLS] listener opened on :8888
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF [WebRTC] listener opened on :8889 (HTTP), :8189 (ICE/UDP)
    2023/11/19 11:00:43 INF [SRT] listener opened on :8890 (UDP)
    2023/11/19 11:00:44 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54189] opened
    2023/11/19 11:00:45 INF [path stream] runOnReady command started
    2023/11/19 11:00:45 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54189] is publishing to path 'stream', 2 tracks (H264, MPEG-4 Audio)
    ffmpeg version N-112782-g07c303b708-20231118 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 13.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.232_c175b21)
      configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20231118
      libavutil      58. 32.100 / 58. 32.100
      libavcodec     60. 33.100 / 60. 33.100
      libavformat    60. 17.100 / 60. 17.100
      libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
      libavfilter     9. 13.100 /  9. 13.100
      libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
      libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
      libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
    2023/11/19 11:00:45 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54191] opened
    2023/11/19 11:00:45 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54191] is reading from path 'stream', 2 tracks (H264, MPEG-4 Audio)
    Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/stream':
      Duration: N/A, start: 0.066000, bitrate: N/A
      Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn
      Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FACEBOOK_STREAM_KEY':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf60.17.100
      Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn
      Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    2023/11/19 11:01:09 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54191] closed: write tcp [::1]:1935->[::1]:54191: i/o timeout
[vost#0:0/copy @ 000002ea9fa8a780] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: End of file
[flv @ 000002ea9fa8d900] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 000002ea9fa8d900] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[out#0/flv @ 000002ea9c93aac0] Error writing trailer: End of file
[out#0/flv @ 000002ea9c93aac0] Error closing file: End of file
[out#0/flv @ 000002ea9c93aac0] video:29kB audio:194kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=       4kB time=00:00:08.39 bitrate=   3.6kbits/s speed=0.07x
Conversion failed!
2023/11/19 11:02:56 INF [path stream] runOnReady command exited: command exited with code 0
```

I want to mention that I've tried streaming exclusively to Facebook from within OBS Studio, and this works fine. So, I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong when using `ffmpeg`.

**Can someone help me crack this nut?**

Answer (score 0):

In your log you have

```
2023/11/19 11:01:09 INF [RTMP] [conn [::1]:54191] closed: write tcp [::1]:1935->[::1]:54191: i/o timeout
```

Which shows that there was an I/O timeout causing the TCP connection to close. Everything after that could be a cascade.

There are a multitude of reasons this could occur.

Improper firewall settings, lack of file permissions, server configuration errors, incorrect credentials, unstable connection and or resource starvation on client or remote machine.

If you can, try to dig into your OBS settings to see if there is something different you have configured for Facebook.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.

I don't think it's a matter of ressources. I'm running a Ryzen 5 5600X and 16 GB RAM, and when streaming in OBS CPU is it 0.8%.

Also, it would surprise me if it was a firewall issue, since I'm streaming out. Nothing is "going in", which is of course require some ports being open. Or am I missing some important detail here?

Comment: The error is happening during a write from port 1935 to 54191 over IPv6. You can try IPv4 or even changing container format or encoding settings. Unfortunately, I don't see an obvious problem at the moment; maybe someone more knowledgeable will. Also, firewalls do block outbound connections, especially on certain ports. It's possible yours is playing a role here.